# Save Compiled TypeScript Files During Webpack Pipeline

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

Is it possible to "intercept & save" the compiled JS files from TypeScript during Webpack's pipeline before Webpack creates the JS bundle?  I'm struggling to find the option that would dump the compiled JS files.

`$ tsc` successfully creates `transpiled/index.js` but `$ webpack` does not, seemingly ignoring the option `tsconfig.json:compilerOptions:outDir`.

**Project Structure**

```
├── dist
│   └── bundle.js
├── src
│   └── index.tsx
├── transpiled
│   └── index.js
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

**index.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const Header = ({ name }: { name: string }) => <h1>{name}</h1>

ReactDOM.render(<Header name="Foo Bar" />, null)
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "outDir": "./transpiled",

    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }],
  },
  output: { filename: 'bundle.js' },
};
```

Comment: I can provide a solution via custom plugin, this is something you consider?

Comment: I'm very curious to know if Webpack can achieve this goal natively without custom plugins. My backup plan is calling `tsc` and running Webpack against that output.

Comment: I'll be surprise if someone will come up with a configuration change solution, it doesn't seems possible without plugins/other process according to the docs https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/

Comment: @RazRonen if you know a good way via plugin, that's definitely something I'd consider!